# How to make a moving circle in Sony Vegas Pro 13? (64bit)

Tags: video-editing, animation, sony-vegas, photo-editing

I am trying to learn how to make a moving circle in a still image on Sony Vegas. This may be difficult to explain, but using those two images below maybe it'll make a little more sense that way.

So, imagine you're drawing a circle with a pen and paper, let's say you're beginning from the upper-most top right hand portion and going counter-clockwise all of the way around until completed. I am bascically trying to do that with the two images provided. I want to start with no circle around to two V's and then have the circle appear in a drawn pattern counter-clockwise until completion.

I know that this may be as odd to teach in writing as it is to explain, so I would greatly appreciate your help in any form. whether it be writing, somebody else's video, or photo demonstration. Am I perhaps using the wrong program (sony vegas) in the first place?

[image]

Comment: You only provided 1 image

Comment: @Dave I apologize for that, I don't seem to have the privileges of posting more than one photo. The other image was essentially the same photo that you see here, minus the circle around the "V." This image is simply the V in addition to the circle

Answer (score 0):

First you should make the circle a separate image form the two Vs. Make sure the circle image has a transparent background. Layer the circle over the Vs and apply the Clock Wipe transition to the start of the circle. It will start from the top and there's nothing to be done about that as far as I'm aware, but it should look something close to what you're looking for.